# Unable to convert string to float in Python

Tags: python, string, csv, types

I'm working with a csv file and one of the columns needs to be converted over to float. This row is giving me an error:

```
2020-10-26,B5,"1,315.89",,10.55,"1,618.87",,"1,911.11",0
```

Specific error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,315.89'

I'd imagine this would apply to other rows after this. Can't figure out why this error is thrown. Thank you.

Looked for any spaces, hidden characters, but nothing is there.

Comment: You need to remove the commas from the numbers before you can parse them as floats.

Comment: `float(value.replace(',',''))`

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Python accepts `_`  as a convenience to give clarity to numbers (so "1_618.87") : it is simply ignored.